# Does running AWS Redshift/taking/keeping snapshot of it run EC2 instance internally?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-redshift

I am running few experiments on AWS Redshift in the free tier with a single node dc2.large cluster. I keep a snapshot as I do not need it to run the cluster at night and again restoring from that snapshot the next morning.

I can see my EC2 bill is slowly rising up with the utility but not a single documentation or blog I could find to understand if a running Redshift cluster uses EC2 instance or taking and keeping a snapshot of a Redshift cluster does the same.

Can anyone help me understanding the behavior?

Comment: How does the your detailed billing report show the EC2 charges? You should look at a deeper level than just seeing the total cost for EC2.

Comment: For further granularity, I look at the Month-to-Date Spend by Service - Bill Details. As of now it is root user and a few people use the same account, hence, its not very clear as to if anybody else is using the EC2 service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your usage of Amazon Redshift (including running a cluster and creating/keeping snapshots) should not create a charge for Amazon EC2 resources.

It might generate traffic within the VPC depending upon how you are connecting to it (eg cross-AZ traffic).

Comment: Yeah, I just saw, some other person was using a different (bigger) cluster of EC2 service which caused this. Thank you!